# How can i override Civicrm /CRM/Utils Files?

Tags: drupal, recaptcha

Override Civicrm Utils file 
/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/ReCAPTCHA.php 
to 
/custom_code/CRM/Utils/ReCAPTCHA.php . 
it is not working. I have cleared the drupal cache and also cleared /civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1 cache. What thing is missing please guide me how can override civicrm files?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should really customize CiviCRM by developing extensions. There is a developer guide that will explain you how this is done: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/

If you do want to override anyway, you should first of all navigate to Administer>System Settings>Directories to provide the path to the PHP files, have you done this? If you have it should work but I would still recommend to take the extensions route as this is by far the most used and supported route.

Comment: Yes , I have already set directories path of php files and also already override some civicrm core files like /custom_code/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Mapping.php file and it is override successfully . but /custom_code/CRM/Utils/ReCAPTCHA.php file is not overriding.

Comment: I understand. I repeat my recommendation to write an extension rather than overriding core files.

Comment: Okay. I am reading https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/.

Comment: Cool, do ask questions if you need any help, either here or on the dev channel on Mattermost?